# To write the value from resultset to text file (.txt file)

Tags: java, text-files, multiple-resultsets

Please help me on the below code as i want to write the values from the resultset to a txt file

**Code**

```
while (rs.next()){
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SBL_PRODUCT_ID")) + ", ");
    out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SBL_TARIFF_ID")) + ", ");
    out.write(rs.getString("PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION") + ", ");
    out.write(rs.getString("SERVICE_TYPE") + ", ");
    out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("MARKET_CLASS")) + ", ");
    out.write(rs.getString("ENTITY_TYPE") + ", ");
    out.newLine();
    /*out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));*/

    System.out.println("Completed writing into text file");
    out.close();
}
```

**Required Output in the txt file**

```
4087, 98, POSTE SIM, Deal [SoHo Flat Tariff Recurring Charge, Prepaid], /service/telco/SIM, 101, DEAL

4087, 99, POSTE SIM, Deal [SoHo Flat Tariff Recurring Charge, Prepaid], /service/telco/SIM, 101, DEAL

4087, 100, POSTE SIM, Deal [SoHo Flat Tariff Recurring Charge, Prepaid], /service/telco/SIM, 101, DEAL

4087, 101, POSTE SIM, Deal [SoHo Flat Tariff Recurring Charge, Prepaid], /service/telco/SIM, 101, DEAL
```

Current output which i am getting is only one line that too the last value from the resultset ie below

**Current output**

```
4087, 101, POSTE SIM, Deal [SoHo Flat Tariff Recurring Charge, Prepaid], /service/telco/SIM, 101, DEAL
```

Kindly help me on this :(

Comment: Open the file once write ALL the content, then close it, once

Comment: i didn't get you could you please provide a snippet

Comment: You're opening the file, writing to and closing on EACH iteration of the `ResultSet` (for each row in the `ResultSet`), not only are you not appending to the file, that's a lot of unnecessary overhead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a large ResultSet to a File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195048/writing-a-large-resultset-to-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create a file writer you're overwriting the file. Change it to:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
while (rs.next()) {            
        out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SBL_PRODUCT_ID")) + ", ");
        out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SBL_TARIFF_ID")) + ", ");
        out.write(rs.getString("PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION") + ", ");
        out.write(rs.getString("SERVICE_TYPE") + ", ");
        out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("MARKET_CLASS")) + ", ");
        out.write(rs.getString("ENTITY_TYPE") + ", ");
        out.newLine();
        /*out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));*/
}
System.out.println("Completed writing into text file");
out.close();
```

Alternatively, you could had set the `append` flag in your `FileWriter`:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

although this is not as efficient as opening the file just once.

Comment: Precisely. Was about to suggest same. Another better way of coding is the one suggested by @MadProgrammer using Java 7 feature, try-with-resources

Answer (score 1):

Open the file once, write the contents to it and THEN close once ALL the content is written, for example

```
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SBL_PRODUCT_ID")) + ", ");
        out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("SBL_TARIFF_ID")) + ", ");
        out.write(rs.getString("PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION") + ", ");
        out.write(rs.getString("SERVICE_TYPE") + ", ");
        out.write(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("MARKET_CLASS")) + ", ");
        out.write(rs.getString("ENTITY_TYPE") + ", ");
        out.newLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Completed writing into text file");
}
```

Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

From GitHub: https://github.com/OhadR/ohadr.common/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ohadr/common/utils/resultset/ResultSetConverters.java

```
public static void writeResultSetToWriter(ResultSet resultSet, PrintWriter writer) throws SQLException
{
ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData();
int numColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();
int numRows = 0;

while(resultSet.next())             //iterate rows
{
    ++numRows;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();      //extends HashMap
    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i)           //iterate columns
    {
        String column_name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
        obj.put(column_name, resultSet.getObject(column_name));
    }
    writer.println(obj.toJSONString());

    if(numRows % 1000 == 0)
        writer.flush();
}
```

}