# Cannot read huge collection from Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, performance, memory-management

what I'm trying to do is to read **1,048,575** records from Oracle DB. The number is not random, it's the max number of rows in Excel file reduced by 1 (I want to have all rows filled + there must be a title row).

My project is built on Spring 4. I'm using `org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor` to get data from database, so basically paging, sorting and `QueryDslPredicates` are required.

When I tried to get all 1,048,575 records I got exception:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. After googling it for a while ([for example there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)) I haven't found any memory leaks. After splitting all records into 100k chunks, it crushed between 500k and 600k.

Project is run on Jetty 9.3 with the following arguments:

```
-Xms512m -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m
```

DB is configured well, it has proper structure and required indexes. Let's say it's immutable.

Having all those in mind, is there any possibility I can actually read that data **without increasing heap size**?

Comment: How do you write the excel file? Also what is the point of the excel file (I mean who need 1M lines in an excel file)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195048/writing-a-large-resultset-to-a-file

Comment: I'm writing the file using Apache POI. I must guarantee users they can download data in .xlsx format.

Comment: see Ruan Rojas's answer in the duplicate

Comment: you mean the 1 accepted? Can't see Ruan Rojas anywhere

Comment: @RC: in the duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195048/writing-a-large-resultset-to-a-file) the only answer was written by BalusC. Were you referring to another question?

Comment: as I understand, you are trying to read these rows from DB in order to create Excel file for your users. What do you think of using PL/SQL procedure while generating .csv file directly on DB site. It could avoid your problem.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274076/writing-a-large-resultset-to-an-excel-file-using-poi?lq=1

Comment: @RC. answer provided in that link is fine for further process - filling the excel file. The problem is, I can't read data from Oracle.

Comment: @Mina I'll try it out, thanks

Comment: reading data could be done by small increments, like 10000 lines a time, the only issue is the time it will take.

Comment: @Mina I have only jdbc connection, I have no access to files generated by DB.

Comment: @RC. combining all your tips brought me the solution - 100k chunks a time and Ruan Rojas' answer were enough. Thanks!

Comment: Good news, don't forget to upvote Ruan answer ;)