# How to work with large database tables in java without suffering performance problems

Tags: java, database, large-data

We have a table of vocabulary items that we use to search text documents.    The java program that uses this table currently reads it from a database, stores it in memory and then searches documents for individual items in the table.    The table is brought into memory for performance reasons.    This has worked for many years but the table has grown quite large over time and now we are starting to see Java Heap Space errors.

There is a brute force approach to solving this problem which is to upgrade to a larger server, install more memory, and then allocate more memory to the Java heap.  But I'm wondering if there are better solutions.    I don't think an embedded database will work for our purposes because the tables are constantly being updated and the application is hosted on multiple sites suggesting a maintenance nightmare.   But, I'm uncertain about what other techniques are out there that might help in this situation.

Some more details, there are currently over a million vocabulary items (think of these items as short text strings, not individual words).   The documents are read from a directory by our application, and then each document is analyzed to determine if any of the vocabulary is present in the document.    If it is, we note which items are present and store them in a database.   The vocabulary itself is stored and maintained in a MS SQL relational database that we have been growing for years.    Since, all vocabulary items must be analyzed for each document, repeatedly reading from the database is inefficient.    And the number of documents that need to be analyzed each day can at some of our installations be quite large (on the order of 100K documents a day).   The documents are typically 2 to 3 pages long although we occasionally see documents as large a 100 pages.

Comment: Exactly how large? You may have some other cause of memory problems but we cannot tell without details.

Answer (score 2):

In the hopes of making your application more performant, you're taking *all* the data out of a database that is *designed with  efficient data operations in mind* and putting it into your application's memory.  This works fine for small data sets, but as those data sets grow, you are eventually going to run out of resources in the application to handle the *entire* dataset.

The solution is to use a database, or at least a data tier, that's appropriate for your use case.  Let your data tier do the heavy lifting instead of replicating the data set into your application.  Databases are incredible, and their ability to crunch through huge amounts of data is often underrated.  You don't always get blazing fast performance for free (you might have to think hard about indexes and models),  but few are the use cases where java code is going to be able to pull an entire data set down and process it more efficiently than a database can.

You don't say much about which database technologies you're using, but most relational databases are going to offer a lot of useful tools for full text searching .  I've seen well designed relational databases perform text searches very effectively.  But if you're constrained by your database technology or your table really is so big that a relational database text search isn't feasible, you should put your data into a searchable cache such as elastic search.  If you model and index your data effectively, you can build a very performant text search platform that will scale reliably.  Tom's suggestion of lucene is another good one.  There's a lot of cloud technologies that can help with this kind of thing too: S3 + Athena comes to mind, if you're into AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at http://lucene.apache.org it should be a good fit for what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a Table with one more than millon of Data and there was a Client that want export all that data. My solution was very simple I followed this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195048/writing-a-large-resultset-to-a-file). But there was a little Issue having more than 100k records go to Heap Space. So I just use `Chunks` with my queries `WITH NO LOCK` ( I know this can have some inconsistent data, but I needed to do that because it was Blocking the DB Without this Statement). I hope this approach help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you had a small table, you probably implemented an approach of looping over the words in the table and for each one looking it up in the document to be processed.

Now the table has grown to the point where you have trouble loading it all in memory. I expect that the processing of each document has also slowed down due to having more words to look up in each document.

If you flip the processing around, you have more opportunities to optimize this process. In particular, to process a document you first identify the set of words in the document (e.g., by adding each word to a Set). Then you loop over each document word and look it up in the table. The simplest implementation simply does a database query for each word.

To optimize this, without loading the whole table in memory, you will want to implement an in-memory cache of some kind. Your database server will actually automatically implement this for you when you query the database for each word; the efficacy of this approach will depend on the hardware and configuration of your database server as well as the other queries that are competing with your word look-ups.

You can also implement an in-memory cache of the most-used portion of the table. You will limit the size of the cache based on how much memory you can afford to give it. All words that you look up that are not in the cache need to be checked by querying the database. Your cache might use a least-recently-used eviction strategy so that you keep the most common words in the cache.

While you can only store words that exist in the table in your cache, you might achieve better performance if you cache the result of the lookup. This will result in your cache having the most common words that show up in the documents being in the cache (and each one with a boolean value that indicates if the word is or is not in the table).

There are several really good open source in-memory caching implementations available in Java, which will minimize the amount of code you need to write to implement a caching solution.